# Entity framework, bindings are destroyed after schema update

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

Related to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768261/datagridview-automatically-generates-columns) about auto generated columns. I have a second problem, the previous problem still occurs after the same action.

I have an entity framework schema. On my form I have several binding sources which use object datasources to the entity framework objects.

When I do a schema update, most of the time I remove the object and add it fresh from the database (because not all database changes are mapper properly to the model). All the mappings to the object are destroyed. In the designer the database properties are still set, but at runtime I get exceptions like: : Cannot bind to the property or column X on the DataSource.".

This is very annoying. Most of the time when I remove bindings and set them again the problem is solved. But this is a hell of a job and should not be necessary.

Anyone knows why this happens and how I can solve this?

Comment: The first issue is that you remove object from designer and add it again. Don't do that and instead use update from database.

Comment: Update from database does not update all columns properly, sometimes mappings are lost or unbound columns are introduced.

Comment: But that is correct behavior which you must fix in the designer. Designer never removes anything from your mapped class it only adds missing properties.

Comment: But it compiles all very well. Only at runtime an exception occurs. It cannot bind to a property, but the property does exists! Now i've removed the bindings and added them again and still I get an exception and i do not know why.

Comment: Now all columns are added to the grid again. But I did not change anything to my EF-model.

Comment: Even worse, after just a schema-update the bindings are destroyed :(