# How do I stop datagridview in winforms automatically generating columns at design time when there is a bindingnavigator?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, entity-framework-5

I am trying to write a header-detail form. in VS2010 C# Winforms. 
The form binds to an Entity Framework class with an property called Attendees 
using a `BindingSource` control called `bindingSource1`.
The grid is bound to another `BindingSource` control  with `datasource = bindingSource1` and `DataMember = Attendees`

I am using code first EF. The entity class is

```
public class ContactEvent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    private readonly BindingList<ContactEventAttendee> _attendees = new BindingList<ContactEventAttendee>();
    public virtual BindingList<ContactEventAttendee> Attendees
    {
        get { return _attendees; }
    }
}
```

I set the columns using the designer, deleting all the columns I don't want. As soon as I save the form and re-open it the columns I dont want are back

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768261/datagridview-automatically-generates-columns?answertab=active#tab-top)  and tried the technique - but it doesn't help. Anyway - my problem shows at design time.

The problem only occurs if I delete all the bound columns.   Since all my columns are unbound this is what I want.

The ContactEventAttendee class is as follows;

```
public class ContactEventAttendee : ILoggedEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid RowId { get; set; }
      [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public int RowVersionId { get; set; }
    public int SourceSiteNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual ContactEvent ContactEvent { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

I get the same problem with another related class as well.
The problem disappears if I delete the bindingNavigator from the form

The data source is

[image: here]

Answer (score 3):

give it a try.

```
public class ContactEvent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ContactEventAttendee> ContactEventAttendees {get; set;}
}
```

**EDIT**

okay, i am having with exact problem when i tried to create a project and set the `DataSource` with your `Class` to `DataGridView` and this another strange bug? well, we really don't know but here my solution.

1. Seperate your `EntityCodeFirst` in another `Class Project` and rebuild this every you made changes.
2. In your main project just add to `Reference` see image below: [image]
3. Now choose the DataSource in your `DataGridView` with the `Object`[image]

Now, try to delete all the columns and rebuild it again.

**EDIT:** Reference of my sample

```
public class ContactEvent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public  ICollection<ContactEventAttendee> _attendees  { get; set;}
}

public class ContactEventAttendee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid RowId { get; set; }
    public int RowVersionId { get; set; }
    public int SourceSiteNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual ContactEvent ContactEvent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: when i try this additional columns still appear. However they are different columns "Count" and "IsReadOnly"

Comment: strange generated columns, i think your using a third party `DataGridView`

Comment: I am using System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView - no 3rd party.
The count and IsReadOnly columns occurred when I tried your suggestion.

Comment: i have put them in the question text.
However I don't see how it can help since the problem is also repeatable with a different class.

Comment: I have the domain classes in a separate project. But the data source looks different to yours.

Comment: if that so, my sample is 100% tested and no generated column was happen :)

Comment: I just added a picture of my datasource to the question.It looks different to yours

Comment: i really don't what is the truly happening from your project. but try to check your classes. i modified my answer for your references.

Comment: I repeated what you have done in a separate project. I never mentioned that I had a bindingNavigator on the form.  As soon as I added it I was able to replicate the problem. Can you also replicate the problem? Steps are add a bindingNavigator and set it's datasource to the same bindingSource as the grid